# Storing lower triangle of a matrix into an array

Tags: java

I want to store the lower triangle of a matrix into a single dimension array.

```
int matrixSample [][]  = {{6,4,1},{7,5,9},{3,2,8}};

6 4 1 
7 5 9 
3 2 8
```

When I print the lower triangle it is fine as it has the respected output.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixSample.length; i++){  
        for(int j = 0; j < matrixSample[0].length; j++){  
          if(i>=j) {             
            System.out.print(matrixSample[i][j] + " "); 
          }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

6 
7 5 
3 2 8
```

The trouble I am having is with the index position when I try to add the diagonals to a separate array. The right values are collected but in the wrong order. My `if()` is allowing `matrix[1][0]` to be stored before `matrix[1][1]`.

```
static int[] getAllDiagonalsInMatrix(int matrix[][]){
    int diagonal[] = new int[matrix.length * (matrix.length - 1)];
    int index = 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
            if(row >= col) {
                diagonal[index] = matrix[row][col];
                index++;
            }           
        }
    }
    return diagonal;
}

[6, 7, 5, 3, 2, 8]
```

The result I am looking for is

```
[6,5,8,7,2,3]
```

Comment: Without the three? To be honest, I would have used the first ordering. The other is fine, you just need to figure out how to put the elements that way.

Comment: AFAIU, you want to have the order like "main diagonal, next to main diagonal, ... lowest diagonal". Looks like the solution is to change the iteration order to that way. BTW, is the matrix always N * N (same count of columns and rows)?

Comment: Yes the rows and the columns are always equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The number of elements in the resulting array is `n * (n + 1) / 2` as it is a sum of arithmetic progression from 1 to `n`
2. When creating the result array, the indexes change like this:

```
0,0; 1,1; 2,2... n,n
1,0; 2,1; n,n-1
...
n,0
```

So the inner loop should be rewritten as shown below:

```java
static int[] getLowerDiagonals(int[][] matrix) {
    int n = matrix.length;
    int m = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    int[] res = new int[m];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            res[k++] = matrix[j + i][j]; 
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Test:

```java
int matrixSample [][]  = {{6,4,1},{7,5,9},{3,2,8}};

for (int[] r : matrixSample) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));    
}

System.out.println("Diagonals: " + Arrays.toString(getLowerDiagonals(matrixSample)));
```

Output:

```
[6, 4, 1]
[7, 5, 9]
[3, 2, 8]
Diagonals: [6, 5, 8, 7, 2, 3]
```

For matrix 4x4, the output is as follows:

```java
int matrixSample [][]  = {{6,4,1,2},{7,5,9,3},{3,2,8,6},{3,1,2,4}};
```

Output:

```
[6, 4, 1, 2]
[7, 5, 9, 3]
[3, 2, 8, 6]
[3, 1, 2, 4]
Diagonals: [6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is the wrong forum to ask but is their a clue in the question to how you know when to use arithmetic progression. Or when to use it when given a problem?

Comment: Let's count elements in the lower triangle starting from the lower left cell by diagonals: first point - 3, next diagonal 1, 3 (2 elements), next 2, 2, 7 (3 elements), and the last one main diagonal of 4 elements 4, 8, 5, 6.  Thus we have progression from 1 to n with step 1, and its sum is `S = (1 + n) * n / 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int[] getAllDiagonalsInMatrix(int matrix[][]){
    int length = matrix.length;
    int diagonal[] = new int[length * (length - 1)];

    for (int n = 0, index = 0; n < length; ++n)
        for (int row = n, col = 0; row < length; ++row, ++col)
                diagonal[index++] = matrix[row][col];
    return diagonal;
}
```

and

```
int matrixSample [][]  = {{6,4,1},{7,5,9},{3,2,8}};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getAllDiagonalsInMatrix(matrixSample)));
```

result:

```
[6, 5, 8, 7, 2, 3]
```